# CSS "overflow" does not show the whole word

Tags: html, css

I have the following arrangement of "divs" in some of these windows, it should be possible to show a scrollbar if the content gets too much. However, the content is then not displayed completely

```css
.main-container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        'table   button'
        'table   word'
        'table   debugger'
        'graph   debugger'
        'graph   debugger'
        'graph   debugger'
        'code    code';
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 48px 48px 1fr 1fr 48px 48px 48px;
    gap: 2px;
}

.sub-container {
    background-color: #4d7ba9;
    border-radius: 0px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

#table-container {
    grid-area: table;
}

#graph-container {
    grid-area: graph;
}

#button-container {
    grid-area: button;
}

#word-container {
    grid-area: word;
}

#debug-container {
    grid-area: debugger;
}

#code-container {
    grid-area: code;
}

#graph-container {
    display: flex;
}

#table-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="sub-container" id="table-container">
    <p id="text">problem</p>
  </div>

  <!-- All containers should remain as they are -->
  <div class="sub-container" id="graph-container">
  </div>

  <div class="sub-container" id="button-container">
  </div>

  <div class="sub-container" id="word-container">
  </div>

  <div class="sub-container" id="debug-container">
  </div>

  <div class="sub-container" id="code-container">
  </div>
</div>
```

the whole word "problem" should be scrollable

If you look at the code in the browser, you can see that the "p" of "problem" is truncated, the larger the word, the more truncated.

In addition, it should be possible to choose a different word or a different size, meaning it shouldn't just be solved with "margin".

Thank you in advance for any solutions or constructive criticism

Comment: From what I understood, the container with word 'Problem' should be scrollable if it overflows (In both x and y direction). Right ?

Comment: scrollable works, but you can´t see the complete "problem" only "roblem" is shown the overflow cuts the word
a bad soulution is: "justify-content: flex-start" but it is nessasary that it is centered

Comment: I checked and the scroll bars are appearing when the content is more than the size of the container. Can I know the browser in which you're testing this ?

Comment: There is a specific fix coming for this. You will be able to use `justify-content: safe center`. This works in Firefox, and in Chrome Canary, but not in the current release of Chrome.

Comment: I use Electron to create an application. Electron unfortunately uses the Chrome browser, is there a solution for this as well?
(Firefox works have tested it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me downsize the example.

```css
.main-container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.sub-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="sub-container">
    <p>abc</p>
  </div>

  <div class="sub-container">
    <p>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here we can see that the second line is clipped off from starting and we cannot scroll to the extreme left.

This happens because in a flexbox, items will not overflow the container's boundaries.

But here is a fix.
To center align the text, instead of using `justify-content: center` on the container, use `margin: auto` on the text.

```css
.main-container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.sub-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: auto;
    width: auto;
}

.sub-container p {
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="sub-container">
    <p>abc</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-container">
    <p>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</p>
  </div>
</div>
```